# How to fix FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION in android

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, android-10.0

In my application I want record screen and I write below codes.
But in **android 10** show me below error :

```
Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
```

**My codes :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".app.services.RecorderService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
        tools:targetApi="q" />
```

I searched on google and stackoverflow, just say to add above codes!
But again not work to me!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this, and it seems to occur when someone updates from an APK that does not include that permission, to one that does. It may also be related to changing the targetSdkVersion from `< 29` to `>= 29`.

I've had unconfirmed reports that a reinstall will get rid of this error.